# Position element perfectly to center (not just for fullscreen)

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, I need to position my element perfectly to the center. It displays correctly in fullscreen mode, however when it's not in fullscreen mode, the element is moved slightly down due to the top of the browser (tabs, URL bar, etc..)

I am using this CSS:

```css
.centered {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

I have a feeling it's centered relative to the screen resolution? (Which explains why it's centered perfectly to fullscreen).

Here are images of what I mean:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/f63l7.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwNfs.png

Is there any way to fix this? I don't mind using HTML/CSS/JS to solve this issue, I can also use JavaScript libraries.

Thanks for any help!

Edit:
My element is inside the body, like this:

```html
<body>
   <img class="centered" src="image.png">
</body>
```

Comment: Does your page scroll vertically when not in fullscreen mode? If so, then your css is probably correct. It's just that the height is longer than what you see on the screen

Comment: I have `overflow` set to `hidden`, so it doesn't show the scroll bar. However, the background image is set to 1920x1080, which is probably the reason to why it's doing it. I'm gonna see if changing the background size to `100%` does something.

Comment: I don't think that's the issue actually. The element is set to absolute, so other elements shouldn't affect it.

Comment: I see. Best would be to remove the `overflow` and set the height to be `100vh` so that it always fills the viewport exactly. Then you don't have to cut off any content from displaying

Comment: @itsanewabstract Thanks for the reply! Setting the `top` property to `50vh` fixed it.

Comment: Great! Glad to help

Comment: @itsanewabstract Any chance you could make an answer on this so I can accept it? Feel free to copy mine in the op, or the one below. (I have to wait 2 days to accept my one...)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216393/discussion-between-itsanewabstract-and-nanoo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of the `vh` unit by changing your code like so:

```
.centered {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50vh;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set parent to `position: relative`.

```css
.parent {
   position: relative;
}
.centered {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span class="centered">I am centered</span>
</div>
```